# convertir object a un int array

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente objeto

```
class MyObj {
   object Value;
   Type ValueType;
}
```

Luego tengo la siguiente situación en la que tengo un objeto cuyo "Value" es un array de int (int[]) pero no se como hacer el parse de este `object Value` a una variable normal `int[] intArray`

```
// la asignación viene de otro lado pero el objeto tiene un int array es decir un int[]
MyObj obj1 = ....

// y lo que yo quiero es tener una variable normal para poder iterar
int[] intArray = obj1.Value.toArray(); //no existe
```

buscando opciones con Convert, Cast, Parse. No logro llegar a una solución

una ayuda pls

PD:
ValueType = {Name = "Int16[]" FullName = "System.Int16[]"}

Comment: Tenes que transformar primero value, a un int[].. proba ((int[])obj1.Value).toArray()

Comment: me apareció error "no se puede convertir int16[] en int32[]" básicamente cambié `int` por `short` y funcionó perfecto gracias estimado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es realizar una [conversión explícita](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#cast-expression).

Es tan simple como escribir entre paréntesis el tipo deseado antes de lo que quieras convertir.

Por ejemplo:

```
object obj = new int[16];
int[] array = (int[])obj;
```

Nota que no se incluye el número de elementos en el tipo ya que es una especie de argumento.

---

El compilador mostrará un error si se detecta que la conversión no es válida.

Puede que el compilador no lo detecte, por lo que la conversión lanzará una excepción si no es válida.

Comment: No se me paso por la cabeza una conversión explicita ._. pero si funcionó a la perfección. Bueno no se me paso por la cabeza porque yo no hice el "new int[]" el objeto me venía así de otro lado. Cosas que pasan mental breakdown supongo

Answer (score 1):

**1.- Casteo simple usando conversión explicita**

Se usan paréntesis `()` para indicar el tipo de datos. Si la conversión falla saltará una excepción

```
MyObj obj1 = new MyObj();
obj1.Value = new List<int>();
int[] intArray = ((List<int>)obj1.Value).ToArray();
```

**2.- Usando operador `as`**

Esta opción permite validar antes de usar, ya que si el casteo falla, no arroja una excepción si no que retorna `null` en su lugar

```
MyObj obj1 = new MyObj();
obj1.Value = new List<int>();

var lista = obj1.Value as List<int>;   //<--aqui
if(lista != null)
{
    int[] intArray = lista.ToArray();
}
```

**3.- Usar genéricos**

Otra opción es usar genéricos, de esta manera decimos explícitamente el tipo de datos y no tenemos que realizar ninguna conversión. Esta es la mejor opción en mi opinión

```
class MyObj<T>
{
    public T Value;
    Type ValueType;
}
```

```
MyObj<List<int>> obj1 = new MyObj<List<int>>();
obj1.Value = new List<int>();
int[] intArray = obj1.Value.ToArray();
```